How to send messages from the serviceA running in a docker container to the serviceB running on the host?
I hava a senrio as follow:
on basic.target stage. My host start running a serviceB, which create a unix socket file "/tmp/.test_sock" when service started.
on the multi-user.target stage. The docker container "test_dc" starting created.
what can i do, to create a volume in the docker test_dc, which is the mount of "/tmp/.test_sock"?
